# DocumentDb, how can I reduce the source to a smaller subset and output in a different shape when original document has no field names

Tags: json, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I have following JSON string which is received from an external party stored in Windows Azure DocumentDb :

```
{
  "kind": "Data",
  "profileInfo": {
    "profileId": "12345",
    "accountId": "12345",
  },
  "rows": [
    [
      "20140925",
      "762"
    ],
    [
      "20140926",
      "552"
    ],
  ]
}
```

I want to reduce the source to a smaller subset and output in a different shape.

"SELECT * FROM date.rows" yield's the subset :

```
[
  [
    [
      "20140925",
      "762"
    ],
    [
      "20140926",
      "552"
    ],
  ]
]
```

Question is since I don't have the field names, how can I modify the output using the "SELECT {"date":?, "value":?} syntax as mention in the DocumentDb documentation?

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you're looking to transform your data to look something like this:

```
[
  {
    date: 20140925,
    value: 762
  },
  {
    date: 20140926,
    value: 552
  }
]
```

In which case you could use the `JOIN` clause to iterate through your document's children (`rows`), and then use the `VALUE` keyword to pull the date and value values out of the queried document.

Here's the query I used to produce the result above:

```
SELECT VALUE {'date': r[0], 'value': r[1]} 
FROM Collections c
JOIN r IN c.rows
WHERE c.kind = "Data"
```

Hopefully this answers your question :)